# Custom Taxonomy as class when outputting a Wordpress Gallery

Tags: wordpress, gallery, taxonomy

So I created a custom taxonomy for my images ("phototype") and I want each term from this taxonomy to be added as a class for the images in the gallery. For example, if I give an image "landscape" as a "phototype", I want the code to display something like:

```
<figure class="gallery-item landscape">
```

I am not sure if I can add this as a filter of some sort or if I must write a custom loop... I need help!

Comment: Is 'phototype' a custom post type?

Comment: No, it is a custom taxonomy that applies to attachments (in my case, images).